# how to write java Log file using the logger api while using hadoop

Tags: java, logging, hadoop

i Wrote a map reduce code that i want to debug.

in order to do so i cant use standard output, because the Hadoop platform doesn't print it to the screen unless an error occurs.

instead i tried to use logger, in order to create log file.

i split it to two files using a handler, unfortunately the "severe" log file comes out empty and the general log file only logs things that happens in the main thread and not in the map reduce functions.

**the question is as follows:**

is there an issue with hadoop and log files or is it a problem with my configuration of the logger? if so how to correct it.

the log configuration code:
i use the one logger for the entire application (this time root logger)

```
public static Logger configureLogging() 
    {
        try
        {
            logger=Logger.getLogger("");
            //FileSystem hdfs=FileSystem.get(URI.create(Misc.S3FS),getConfiguration());
            logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);

            //StreamHandler handler=new StreamHandler(hdfs.create(new Path(Misc.LOGS_PATH+"mylog.log")),new SimpleFormatter());
            FileHandler handler=new FileHandler(Misc.LOGS_PATH+"mylog.xml",true);   
            FileHandler severeHandler=new FileHandler(Misc.LOGS_PATH+"mylogSevere.xml",true);
            severeHandler.setLevel(Level.INFO);
            logger.addHandler(handler);
            logger.addHandler(severeHandler);

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return logger;

    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Hadoop comes with preconfigured log4j. All you have to do is import two classes:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
```

And now you can define logger inside your mappers, reducers and wherever you want:

```
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
```

And log what you need:

```
LOG.info("My message");
```

The messages will show up during job execution. You can tweak log4j configuration with

```
conf/log4j.properties
```

Comment: hi is there anyway not to interfere with the hadoop logger? and write my log to a file separately (also im not familiar with log4j platform

Comment: tried your method unfortunately it didn't seem to work. it still only shows the map % reduce % and none of my log massages appear.